# How to protect yourself from being misrepresented by others?

Tags: work-environment, work-time, working-conditions, presentations

This can be a problem stemming either from the boss, or co-workers competing for promotions.

Examples include(what other people do)

- writing inaccurate details in email causing other people(who may or may not have a good understanding of the work we're doing) get wrong impressions
- passing comments which are not true objectively, distorting reality.

I'm not insinuating that people I work with are evil, in fact, I keep a positive attitude and give them the benefit of doubt. But there are 10% of people who employ such cheap tactics to create a stressful environment.

I would like some opinions on the kind of challenges people face, and how do they handle such challenges at their workplace. 
I'm a data analyst and would prefer to hear from experienced people with a similar work profile.

Comment: The promotion evaluation system is supposed to be based on objectives and facts. On the email case, don't give others means to misunderstand it, be factual and objective. On the comments, validate whether it's perception or bad-faithed people. If it's perception, just adapt based on their feedbacks when you interact with them. if it's bad-faithed people, you'll have to put them in front on their lies 1-on-1 with a neutral witness and remind them kindly that diffamation against someone is not professional at all and is punished by the law (being kind doesn't work with this type of people).

Comment: Please consider changing the questions asked at the end of your post so it's less about opinions and more about facts and ways to deal with your predicament, so it's not primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Answers_Seeker that could be a full fledged question, consider elaborating it into one!

Comment: @Leon : Based on the examples in the bulletpoint, OP seems to be asking for clues to prevent inaccurate evaluation feedbacks. I adressed the case of the email and the case of the comments. For the comments, you end-up most of the time facing 2 scenarios (not adapting to the interlocutor/doing something taken in a bad way VS people who are clearly aiming to put down others).

Comment: @Answers_Seeker I'm not opposing the core of your answer, merely suggesting you flesh out an answer below rather than using the comments to answer. I would upvote such an answer tbh.

Comment: @Leon : Will do, got mistaken by the question word :)

Answer (score 3):

The promotion evaluation system is supposed to be based on objectives and facts.

Usually, you have to set metrics and objectives on which the manager is supposed to rely on with him.

The emotional aspect can be part of keys to improvement if it's not something grave.
However, good managers will know that this aspect is not rational and can't be fully relied on (person not liking other's face for example).

To come back to your question:

- On the email case, don't give others means to misunderstand it, be factual and objective. In the worse case, they'll say that you are an emotionless robot :)
- On the comments, you'll need to validate whether it's perception or bad-faithed people.

Following if the comments are based on perception or if it's people who are people others down, you should:

- **Perception:** Adapt to your interlocutor based on his/her feedbacks when you interact with them. Funny Data science Example: Don't suggest a dataset about how good meat is if your interlocutor is vegan
- **Bad-faithed people**: you'll have to put them in front on their lies 1-on-1 with a neutral witness and remind them kindly that diffamation against someone is not professional at all and is punished by the law. The neutral witness is very important as the bad faithed-person can transform everything you said. By doing this, you are making the person **acknowledge his/her mistake** and **highlighting the consequences of such behavior**.

Already lived this situation and in the end, IMHO, that's the best approach I found through failures.

You can't go against people instictive perception as it's usually the result of their lifetime construction and experiences. You just have to adapt to it as you say "Sir" as a sign of respect.

I tried the nice way several times with bad-faithed people and ended-up always getting backstabbed. They usually forget that diffamation is illegal and that they can lose both professionally (would you trust a ressource that lies ?) and personnaly (court decision).